# How to get a function to work the way I want

Tags: python-3.x

Basically, I need my program to end up like this when it is ran:

```
>>> inchesToMeters(1)
0.0254
```

The program that needs to be created is one that converts inches to meters.  Here is what I have so far:

```
def inchesToMeters(a):
    meters = a * 0.0254
    return meters

def main():
    a = float(input("Enter the amount of inches you wish to convert to meters: "))
    inches_in_meters = inchesToMeters(a)
    print(inches_in_meters)

main()
```

My issue is, the professor does not want any sort of text, such as the question from variable a.  He just wants to run the program, and it to end up as:

```
>>> inchesToMeters(1)
0.0254
```

Where all it says is inchesToMeters( ) and you just enter a number the answer appears on the bottom.  How do I go about doing this?  Any help would be greatly appreciated for this coding newb, thanks!

Comment: From what I can understand you just want one function...not two?

Comment: Your example at the end is not the same as "just wants to run the program". For the letter, use `sys.argv` to obtain command line arguments (such as the number of meters).

Comment: Correct I just want one function.  I'm very new and the professor has not given much guidance.  With my original code, when the program runs, it will ask on scree, "Enter the amount of inches you wish to convert to meters: "

But I cant have that, all I can have come up when the program runs is:

inchesToMeters ( ) where I enter any number and it returns the value

Answer (score 0):

Put the function (by itself) in a module called `something.py`. Choose a better name then something. Make sure it is in your python path somewhere, then execute:

```
>>> import something
>>> something.inchesToMeters(1)
0.0254
```

Of course, am assuming the example you gave what you wanted. Suspect this may not be the case...